# Calculate rates of change

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If a hemispherical bowl has a radius r cm and is binef filled with water at a constant rate. Then how do you show that when the dept of water in the bowl is h cm, then the volume of water in the bowl is given by the formula :

$$\frac{\pi h^2(3r - h)}{3}$$

Then how can you show that between the time when the water is halfway to the top and the time when it is about to overflow, the rate at which the depth is rising has fallen by a quarter

Comment: For the first question, you can try integrating the solid formed by rotating a curve around $y$-axis: $$\int_{-r}^{-r+h}\pi\left(r^2-y^2\right)dy$$

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution to the first question in the following link http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCap.html

With respect to the second question, we have that $V'=\frac{dV}{dt}$ is constant, say $c.$ That, is

$$c=V'(t)=\pi h(2r-h)h'.$$ So, we have that

$$h'(t)=\frac{c}{\pi h(2r-h)}.$$ Now, when $h=r/2$ we have $$h'=\frac{4c}{3\pi r^2}$$ and when $h=r$ it is $$h'=\frac{c}{\pi r^2}.$$ Then, we have $$\frac{3}{4} \frac{4c}{3\pi r^2}=\frac{c}{\pi r^2},$$ that is, the rate at which the depth is rising has fallen by a quarter.